# Prolog: generate a term from a list according to DCG

Tags: list, prolog, dcg, parse-tree

I have the following DCG:

```
s   --> np, vp.

np  --> det, n.

vp  --> v.

det --> [the].

n   --> [cat].

v   --> [sleeps].
```

I can verify sentences like `s([the,cat,sleeps], [])`, and I get the reply "`yes`".

But I need this sentence as a term, like: `s(np(det(the),n(cat)),vp(v(sleeps)))`.

How can I can I generate the term from the list `[the,cat,sleeps]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to extend your current DCG to include an argument which defines the term you're after:

```
s(s(NP, VP))  -->  np(NP), vp(VP).

np(np(Det, Noun))  -->  det(Det), n(Noun).
vp(vp(Verb))  -->  v(Verb).

det(det(the))  -->  [the].

n(n(cat))  -->  [cat].

v(v(sleeps))  -->  [sleeps].
```

Then you call it using `phrase`:

```
| ?- phrase(s(X), [the, cat, sleeps]).
X = s(np(det(the),n(cat)),vp(v(sleeps)))
```

The code might look a little confusing since the term names you want happen to match the predicate names you've selected. Renaming the predicates, to make it a little clearer:

```
sentence(s(NP, VP))  -->  noun_part(NP), verb_part(VP).

noun_part(np(Det, Noun))  -->  determiner(Det), noun(Noun).
verb_part(vp(Verb))  -->  verb(Verb).

determiner(det(the))  -->  [the].

noun(n(cat))  -->  [cat].

verb(v(sleeps))  -->  [sleeps].

| ?- phrase(sentence(X), [the, cat, sleeps]).
X = s(np(det(the),n(cat)),vp(v(sleeps)))
```

If you want to augment this by, for example, including more nouns, you could do it this way:

```
noun(n(N)) --> [N], { member(N, [cat, dog]) }.
```

With a general query result:

```
| ?- phrase(sentence(X), L).

L = [the,cat,sleeps]
X = s(np(det(the),n(cat)),vp(v(sleeps))) ? a

L = [the,dog,sleeps]
X = s(np(det(the),n(dog)),vp(v(sleeps)))

(1 ms) yes
| ?-
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! just what I was looking for!